# Not able to print a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list

I converted a list to a dataframe using the following code:

```
List1 = ['apple', '123', 'xy24']
df = pd.DataFrame(List1)
df
```

Output:

```
(Nothing)
```

It's not displaying the dataframe.

I tried printing the list by giving

```
print(List1)
```

Output:

```
['apple', '123', 'xy24']
```

Comment: Try `print(df)` instead of just `df`.

Comment: Usually str() and repr() are used to print something understandable, but without knowing wich IDE you are using it is impossible to say why the output is empty. however,  a `print(df)` maybe is enough.

Comment: Simply calculating things will not cause anything to display *in a script*. That *only* happens at an interpreter prompt, and it happens because *the prompt* is displaying the computed result, not the Python code. Please see the linked duplicate for details.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
from IPython.display import display
display(df)
```

output

```
       0
0  apple
1    123
2   xy24
```